# Why does the SSRS throw #Error for displaying Multi Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am using a split_string delimiter to be able to choose from multiple values from the SSRS report. I am able to select Multi Values in the SSRS report but the SSRS displays `#Error` where the multi value should be.

Picture for reference

[image]

This is what my expression for the report looks like

[image]

The `count` and `ismultivalue` in the expression works just fine

For Example:

I am using `isMultiValue` in the expression and it works fine

[image]

but `Label` and `value` throws `#Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your report expression you are referecing the `Parameter` rather than the value that is passed to your Dataset, so successfully using a `string_split` function in the Dataset is actually unrelated here.

This is because multi valued parameters are Objects and not simple scalar values.  When you do a `count` on the `Parameter` you are counting the items in the Object, which is a valid operation.

However, the `Parameter` object can't show you a single `Value` or a `Label` as it doesn't know *which* `Value` or `Label` to show you, even if there is only one item in the `Parameter` object.

What you need to do instead, is use a zero based Index value to specify which item you want to display:

```
="Bkt: " & Parameters!BKT.Label(0)
```

or tell SSRS to display *all* the items within the `Parameter` object as a list:

```
="Bkt: " & join(Parameters!BKT.Label,", ")
```

Comment: The second way worked, thank you so much. I really appreciate it

Comment: @VonOurt  No worries, glad you got it working :)